# Nativescript provisioning for distribution not working: Error ITMS90161

Tags: ios, nativescript

I created a distribution certificate, app identifier and a provisioning profile to tie them together. I created an app in the app store connect portal. As far as I can see, everything matches (app bundle, version, app name)

When I run:

```
tns publish ios <apple id> <password> <provision uuid> <code signing id>
```

I get the following error:

ERROR: ITMS90161: "Invalid provisioning profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A distribution provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the app store"

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: I hope you are using the right provisional profile type (distribution). Is the provisional profile installed in your machine? Did you try publishing manually form Xcode with same certificate and provisional, error persists? You could do this by running `tns build` then open the compiled Xcode project inside platforms folder, try creating an archive with same certificate and provisional.